# Rose colored wine cocktail

Tags: wine, recommendations, ingredients, cocktails

I have no experience in making [wine cocktails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_cocktail) and I would like a recommendation of a "rose" colored wine cocktail.

The wine cocktail I am looking for should be as close as possible to the color [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(color)) as possible. The color [pink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink) is generally much lighter in color than that of rose.

> [Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(color)) is the color halfway between red and magenta.
>
> [Pink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink) is a pale red color which takes its name from the flower of the same name.

If possible could answers include why one is making their recommendations, a recipe for usage and an image of the suggested wine cocktail or wine cocktails (if possible).

Comment: Is this for a romantic evening?  Is the color so very important?

Comment: Not a cocktail, but rosé wine comes in a variety of hues from pale pink to dark magenta.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 The hue is important for a  meal which is linked to a traditional religious celebrations. Rose is a liturgical color as well a the tradition color used in the interior of the Grand Chartreuse. I like to celebrate my Feasts with great meaning and symbolism! There are many Carthusian  saints.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, I believe we are on the opposite ends of that spectrum, but it wont stop my dougal nose trying to sniff something out for you.  However, I think that @Dorothy has beaten us all to it with her answer below - which seems to cover just about everything - I hope your event is a success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do love a wine spritzer and cocktails, as you can take a fabulous wine, white or red, add splashes of other liquid(s) for a light and refreshing drink. I also love your questions, and would like to be your neighbor, invited over for drinks (I'll bring the hors d'oeuvres).

So, for your glorious rose-colored beverages, along with rosy images!

[Tinto de Verano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinto_de_verano)

[image]

1 part red wine
1 part "gaseosa" (carbonated lemon-flavored soda)
Traditional-flavored gaseosa can be replicated by mixing Sprite or 7-Up with carbonated water.

Serve over ice with a slice of lemon.

[René Barbier Mediterranean Red Citrus Wine Cooler](https://www.renebarbierusa.com/red-citrus-cocktail-recipe.php)

[image]

3 oz. René Barbier Mediterranean Red
1/4 oz. orange liqueur
Juice of 1/4 lime
4 oz. lemon/lime soda

In a highball glass half-filled with ice, add orange liqueur, lime juice and red wine. Swirl gently to mix and then add soda. Garnish with orange wedge or lime twist. Serves one.

[The Rumbling Red Horse](https://tallhorsewines.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/my-new-summer-cocktail-%E2%80%93-a-rumbling-red-horse/)

[image]

50 ml fresh lemon juice
100 ml Red wine – Tall Horse Merlot or Cabernet
Lemonade (to your liking)
1 teaspoon superfine sugar

Add sugar, lemon juice to you preferred glass and muddle until sugar dissolves. Add ice, wine and the lemonade to fill. Garnish with lemon slice or cherry.

[Kir and Kir Royale](http://www.thekitchn.com/kir-and-kir-royale-a-guide-to-124781)

[image]

1/5 Crème de Cassis to
4/5 chilled dry white wine
(or chilled dry Champagne for Royale)

Add the room-temperature Crème de Cassis to the glass first, followed by the wine (otherwise, they do not mix very well or uniformly).

[Pretty in Pink Wine Cocktail](https://www.mysanfranciscokitchen.com/pretty-in-pink-wine-cocktail/)

[image]

12 oz Gallo Family Pink Moscato
2 oz cherry brandy
¼ cup chopped, pitted cherries
4-6 strawberries, hulled and sliced (plus more for garnish)
2 stems of fresh mint leaves

Add the cherries to the bottom of an 8-oz glass, followed by 1-oz cherry brandy. Divide the moscato into each glass, and drop the sliced strawberries and mint on top. Garnish with a fresh strawberry on the side of the glass and serve chilled. Makes 2 cocktails.

[Strawberry Peach Sangria](https://learn.winecoolerdirect.com/summer-wine-cocktails/)

[image]

1 bottle of dry white wine
6 oz. of orange muscat wine
4 oz. of peach schnapps
8 oz. of strawberries cut into slices
3 peaches cut into slices
1 lemon cut into slices

Combine all the ingredients together in one pitcher. Pour over ice.

And, just in case you want a full-on killer cocktail: [Maria McClaire](http://portcocktails.com/cocktails.html)

[image]

1 1/2 oz. Irish whiskey
1 oz. Fonseca Siroco White Port
1/2 oz. Campari
2 dashes Peychaud's Bitters

Strain into a chilled cocktail glass and twist a thin-cut swatch of orange peel over the top.

Comment: Wow, now that is what I call an answer!

Comment: Which Irish Whiskey(ies) would you suggest as a mixer in a cocktail?